# In which region the intensity of black bodies is maximum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

My teacher said it's infrared but according to the graph shouldn't it be the visible region ?
[Why aren't the graphs for black body radiation straight lines?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52494/317518)

Comment: Black bodies *at what temperature*?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law

Comment: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVkcGO2jAQhu-W_A4jeohNTYidEMhKkapKVLuHSqhCHBeZYDZuQkIds01Y9d3rENjV-uKZb_75x9Z8gVUpq6yAXSmzYlfvOzByr6XVdeXD6ieIX7p6wSiDFESSzBMRzRYY5S6N_VjEwTzgs-UkjDAqHON-uAjiKFlORIiR2lxRHAg-j-MwWk54gpHsrfyF4FGYhHPBhQCMMPqmK6uMzCxGe3WALVmnYRDQB4zAncL2IwsYwxqmkA_wpGQ_VDrq6gN7deDKx5A7pdrcpMbZk8OoLz3A2_XyI_UPHi8M3rLpBzi6_HUI1WZEh_ayZpDru_UUeMzuU6JB0bkiEeN8mj0L6nD7HDodUe2JtC5w76MwAX7zW_VWZW1Jx4C07OZPGbwYvS91pZp0dJS_azN6b_jqOur-E6QfzKAjbdpHlN4lfpPXf8nByKNK1-asGFhtS5V6399325xUZs356DGQrWq2pdypskmJ98OoP2dVZR2Qxwt1Ze_JraNqtO08-km8bfRFpdznM_ofGYKZjw==&lang=sage

Comment: @PM2Ring thnx a lot 
so at lower temperature, it's IR region

Comment: Yes. And at even lower temperature the peak is in the microwave region. Eg, the CMB is at a temperature of ~2.73 kelvin.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graphic in the linked question show the intensity curves for black bodies at different temperatures.  The one peaked in the visible is for $T=6000K$, approximately the temperature of the Sun.  The curves for lower temperatures, e.g. $2000K$, and $3000K$ are peaked in the infrared.

The location of the peak is described by [Wien's displacement law](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/University_Physics_III_-_Optics_and_Modern_Physics_(OpenStax)/06%3A_Photons_and_Matter_Waves/6.02%3A_Blackbody_Radiation):

$$
\lambda_{max} = \frac{b}{T}
$$
with $b=2.897771955 \times 10^{−3} m \cdot K$ and $T$ is the temperature of the blackbody.